# Changing default log dir of btmp and wtmp

Tags: linux, logs, login, wtmp

I've mounted my external drive which serves as different `log` dir.

Everything is configured to write to my external location named `/var/log_external`, and I am wondering, is possible to change default dir of `wtmp` and `btmp` to something like `/var/log_external/wtmp` ?

Considering that both are binaries, I wasn't able to find a way to do it correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Binary has no bearing on the issue. `wtmp`'s location is defined by the FHS (tools expect it to be there and will break otherwise), thus your only option will be something like a symlink or bind mount.